# What different lines of reasoning and traditions lead to the conclusion that Software Engineering is or isn't part of Computer Science?

Tags: software-engineering

**Background:** Some people consider Software Engineering as a branch of Computer Science, while others consider that they are, or should be, separate. The former stance seems to be well presented in written works. On Wikipedia, Software Engineering [is classified as Applied Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science#Areas_of_computer_science), along with, e.g., Artificial Intelligence and Cryptography. The [ACM Computing Classification](http://www.acm.org/about/class/ccs98-html) system places SE under Software, along with, e.g., Programming Languages and Operating Systems. [CSAB](http://www.csab.org/) has also [considered SE as part of Computer Science](http://web.archive.org/web/20090117183438/http://www.csab.org/comp_sci_profession.html), and considered that

> [...] it includes theoretical studies, experimental methods, and engineering design all in one discipline. [...] It is this close interaction of the theoretical and design aspects of the field that binds them together into a single discipline.
>   [...]
>   Clearly, the computer scientist must not only have sufficient training in the computer science areas to be able to accomplish such tasks, but must also have a firm understanding in areas of mathematics and science, as well as a broad education in liberal studies to provide a basis for understanding the societal implications of the work being performed.

While the above seems to reflect my own view, there is also the stance that the term Computer Science should be reserved for what is sometimes called Theoretical Computer Science, such as Computability Theory, Computational Complexity Theory, Algorithms and Data Structures, and that other areas should be split off into their own disciplines. In the introductory courses I took for my CS degree, the core of CS was defined via the questions "what can be automated?" (Computability Theory) and "what can be automated efficiently?" (Computational Complexity Theory). The "how" was then explored at length in the remaining courses, but one could well consider SE being so far from these core questions that it shouldn't be considered part of CS.

Even [here on CS.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-our-stance-on-software-engineering), there has been debate about whether SE questions are on-topic, reflecting the problematic relationship between CS and SE.

**Question:** I'm wondering what lines of reasoning and traditions within Computer Science might lead to one conclusion or the other: that SE is, or should be, part of CS or that it is not. (This implies that answers should present both sides.)

Comment: This has the risk of being too subjective.

Comment: I don't think people want to have CS=TCS. That's a different statement from SE $\notin$ TCS. Regarding Dave's comment, answer should include authorative evidence, not only bare opinion or experience.

Comment: @DaveClarke: True, and if that happens, the question should probably be closed. Hopefully, respondents can bring plenty of references to back up their answers.

Comment: @Raphael: True, the statements are different. But I do think some would prefer to keep CS as close to TCS as possible, and see SE $\notin$ CS as a fact, or at least as desirable. I would love to be proven wrong, of course.

Comment: you dont really say what the end goal of your question is. are you talking about, [it seems] how should college courses be organized? historically computer science/software engineering were paradigm shifting in academia which is slow moving, where some disciplines have stayed unchanged for near centuries. looks like software engineering is a later concept than computer science that acknowledges that computer science has strong real world applications & can be used to "build stuff & systems". so think its fair to say there will always be strong overlap into the future, and some parts disjoint

Comment: also, I wonder at times if this type of question is mainly about how college departments are funded, & budgets, & departmental authority/jurisdiction within the university system....

Comment: My understanding is that in the U.S. the use of the word engineering is controlled by the government for use with issuing engineering licenses. Since the government controls the use of the word engineering and the licenses, the issue is a legal issue. See [Regulation and licensure in engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Engineer)

Comment: Tempted to close as NARQ. This is ultimately a list question: you want a list of arguments pro and con SwE being considered a part of CS. I give three ways of looking at it; but any way of looking at it is potentially valid (and someone's not being "authoritative" doesn't do much to change that).

Comment: Voted to close as inherently subjective.

Comment: Also voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: ps: A claim like "there is also the stance that the term Computer Science should be reserved for what is sometimes called Theoretical Computer Science" needs to be supported by *good* examples. You have made a claim without giving any support for it and you are asking why people think so.

Comment: @Kaveh: You should read more carefully; the claim is that the stance exists, so a single example should suffice. I've given more than that by the meta.CS.SE link, which I think contains ample evidence of good examples.

Comment: I am sure we can find people holding various kinds of beliefs, the existence of people holding those beliefs does not make a question. Others cannot read the mind of people who you are claiming to say that SE is not part of CS. I don't think anyone in the meta thread claimed that SE is not part of CS.

Comment: As a computer scientist currently teaching software engineering, I can assure you (anecdotally, of course), that they are different disciplines.

Comment: @Kaveh: No "mind reading" is necessary. One answer in the meta thread said: "In my opinion, SE and CS will have to separate at some point in the future; methods and mindset are too different." If you read the articles in my answer, you'll find many examples of similar opinions. Also, why do you think people holding beliefs are not ground for questions? The demarcation of any field of science is made by humans based on their beliefs. There is nothing in nature that partitions, e.g. a flower into its biology, chemistry, physics, or mathematics. Humans make those choices.

Comment: It seems that you are confusing TCS with CS. Anyway, I still think this is not a real question, it is like asking something like "why some people think emacs is not an editor?" but I am not going to argue any further.

Comment: @Kaveh: Why would the editor question not be real?. Anyway, you are giving an excellent example of why this question is both real, valid, and important: unable to grasp the question, you fail to acknowledge that you can't answer it, and mistakenly assume that it is therefore not real nor answerable. You then invent a reason for why the questioner is confused. I don't blame you – it's a difficult question. Many have thought about it, but it still comes up and causes confusion. As you can see in my answer here on CS.SE, there are answers. The point of this site is to share those, right?

Comment: "Not a real question" is the name of one of the closing reasons on SE software. It reads as follows: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Anyway, as I said I am not going to argue with ouy any further.

Comment: @Kaveh: I know the definition of NARQ. The question is, what is the required area and level of knowledge for a particular SE site? The editor question clearly belongs on some other SE site, because the answer is outside the scope of Computer Science, but it's not NARQ per se. This question, on the other hand, is about the very essence of Computer Science, so it's within scope. The fact that it's pretty difficult to answer doesn't mean it's NARQ. I think I demonstrated that in my answer. The reason I keep replying here is that I think this question is important for people interested in CS.

Comment: Much of what is considered hard core computer science (operating systems, compilers and similar stuff) is in some sense higher-level software engineering (the Linux kernel, at 13 million lines of code, is certainly software engineering). The building of software in turn depends on algorithms, which are part of the realm of the "purest" TCS. I consider this question as partly meanigless, as there is a continuum, and "practical" distinctions are essentially an arbitrary cut point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I did some extensive searching and found material that answers my question. I liked Patrick87's answer, but I found this to be more complete.)

The answer to the question lies in a careful examination of the philosophy of Computer Science. In Computer Science, three intellectual traditions meet (or collide, if you wish) in a single discipline: the theoretical tradition; the empirical tradition; and the engineering tradition.

The theoretical tradition concerns itself with creating hypotheses or theorems, and proving them in a mathematical fashion. Its aim is the construction of coherent axiomatic systems of thought.

The empirical tradition concerns itself with forming hypotheses, models, and predictions, collecting data from experiments, and analysing the results. Its aim is to investigate and explain phenomena.

Finally, the engineering tradition concerns itself with stating requirements and specifications, and with designing, implementing, and testing systems based on these requirements and specifications. Its aim is to construct systems and solve concrete instances of problems.

Each of these traditions comes with a set of assumptions about the aims and means of scientific inquiry.

The traditions are not unique to Computer Science; they are general traditions that can be found to differing degrees in other disciplines. Perhaps the clearest examples are mathematics (theoretical tradition), physics (empirical tradition), and construction engineering (engineering tradition). Computer Science, though, operates in the intersection of all three traditions. However, depending on one's particular focus within Computer Science, and one's familiary with other parts of Computer Science, one might emphasize one of these traditions to the degree that the other two appear alien.

As noted in Patrick87's answer, the educational setting can emphasize a certain intellectual tradition which may lead someone to a certain kind of demarcation of Computer Science which either includes or does not include Software Engineering. Similarly, one may later adopt a view of science that includes or excludes one or more of the three traditions, or parts of them. For example, one may consider only the theoretical and empirical traditions to fulfil one's criteria for "science", and consider engineering non-scientific. One may also consider the three traditions to be on a value continuum, with one tradition being superior to the others (e.g. valuing the theoretical tradition most, the empirical tradition less, and the engineering tradition least).

So the lines of reasoning are rooted in the abovementioned traditions. Based on this, the answer to the question is that considering Software Engineering as part or not as part of Computer Science stems from one's understanding of science in general, and of one's understanding of the philosophy of Computer Science in particular.

The following articles go into considerable depth on this issue and summarise a lot of the viewpoints that have been put forward.

> [Tedre, Matti (2011) Computing as a Science: A Survey of Competing Viewpoints. Minds & Machines 21(3):pp.361-387.](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Tedre,%20Matti%3a%20Computing%20as%20a%20Science%3a%20A%20Survey%20of%20Competing%20Viewpoints)
>
> [Tedre, Matti (2009) Computing as Engineering. Journal of Universal Computer Science 15(8):pp.1642-1658](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Tedre,%20Matti%3a%20Computing%20as%20Engineering)
>
> [Tedre, Matti (2007) Know Your Discipline: Teaching the Philosophy of Computer Science. Journal of Information Technology Education 6(1):pp.105-122.](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Tedre,%20Matti%3a%20Know%20Your%20Discipline%3a%20Teaching%20the%20Philosophy%20of%20Computer%20Science)

Comment: Too bad I can't upwote twice ;-)

Answer (score 4):

One might base such a decision on the kind of education and training expected of practitioners. A good source for investigating differences and similarities in this direction might be the [ACM curriculum guidelines](http://www.acm.org/education/curricula-recommendations) for computing professions, including CS and SwE.

Another might be in terms of the economic profile of these professional fields. The latest edition of the [US Bureau of Labor Statistics Occupational Outlook Handbook](http://www.bls.gov/ooh/) provides a good deal of information comparing these fields' economic and social aspects.

One might take a more philosophical approach and ask what the fields are, in themselves, and how they are similar and different in that respect. The question of how, if at all, to distinguish between science and engineering is a long one, and e.g., David Parnas saw a distinction in this way (see the [Computer science Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science#Name_of_the_field)).